# NPOI , XSSFComment c#: Unable to set Background color for the comment

Tags: c#, apache-poi, npoi

I need to create an excel (XLSX) file with comments. I was able to achieve the same using  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonyqus/npoi/master/examples/xssf/CreateCommentInXlsx/Program.cs

but I didn't find any function to set Background color for the comments . By default it's transparent.
Using HSSF(XLS) it works fine as I see SetFillColor function under HSSFComment class for setting Background color for the comments .For XSSF Its not available under XSSFComment.

Please help me to add a background color to the comment in XLSX File.

Thanks,
Bk

Comment: Any response guys ?

Comment: I completed by using HSSFComment.XSSFCOMMENT does not support background color change in the comment bubble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed by using HSSFComment.XSSFCOMMENT does not support background color change in the comment bubble.